# How change the order and integrate this function $e^{x^{2}}$?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

I need to change the order of integration and evaluate the following:

$\int_{0}^{1} \int_{\sqrt{y}}^{1} e^{x^2}dxdy$

$x=\sqrt{y}, x=1$

Would this work: $\int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{x^2} e^{x^3}dydx$ ?

Comment: Your notation is ambigious. Please write integrals at $\int_a^b \dots \,\color{red}{\mathrm dx}$ etc. so that we know what is the integration variable.

Comment: Sorry about that; I added them in.

Comment: I believe you got the right idea, except that $e^{x^2}$ should not have become $e^{x^3}$

Comment: Draw a picture!  You must draw a picture when you first start working on these problems to build an intuition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The original domain is $0 \le y \le 1, \sqrt{y} \le x \le 1$

It is equivalent to $0 \le x \le 1, 0 \le y \le x^2$.

Hence the part about changing the variable is correct, however, note that the function that you are integrating should remain the same.

\begin{align}
\int_0^1 x^2 \exp(x^2) \, dx &= \int_0^1 \frac{x}2 (2x) \exp(x^2) \, dx \\
&= \frac{x}2 \exp(x^2) |_0^1 - \int_0^1 \frac12 \exp(x^2) \, dx \\
&= \frac{e}2 - \frac12 \int_0^1 \exp(x^2) \, dx \\
&= \frac{e}{2} -  \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{4}erfi(1)
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks, so it should be $\int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{x^2} e^{x^2}dydx$. But when integrating this, I am stuck at $\int_{0}^{1} e^{x^2}x^2dx$ because substitution creates more variables, and by parts doesn't seem to be getting me anywhere.